# Download Image and UIButton BG image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I am trying to do download some images from server then , set these images as background image for some UIButtons .

so first downloading images :

```
NSString *urlMag1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myweb.com/i224_mag1.png"];
    NSString *urlMag2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myweb.com/i224_mag2.png"];
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:urlMag1,urlMag2,nil];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:str];
    NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    UIImage *imgMag1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"i224_mag2.png"];
    [mag2 setBackgroundImage:imgMag1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

but nothing happens !!,and how can I check to if these images are in directory to avoid more downloading

I would be grateful if you help me to solve this

thanks !

**EDITED**
@Fernando Cervantes

I created a method to set buttons BG images something like this , but I don't know why does not work !

```
- (UIImage *)loadImages :(NSString *)fileNames ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", fileNames, extension]]];
    return 0;
}
```

and set BG images :

```
- (void)buttonsBGImage {



    UIImage * bgMag2 = [self loadImages:@"i224_mag2" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]];

    [mag2 setBackgroundImage:bgMag2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];


}
```

but actually nothing happens ! even I check the file and it's in app directory

Comment: Are you trying to download those images from a webserver?  If so you need to use NSURLConnection to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach might help you out a bit.

**Save**

```
-(void) saveFile:(NSString *)fileName ofType:(NSString *)extension fromURL:(NSString *)fileIndexPath inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileIndexPath]];

    [data writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@", directoryPath, fileName, extension] atomically:YES];
}
```

**Check**

```
-(BOOL) checkIfFileExists:(NSString *)fileName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectoryPath:(NSString *)directoryPath {
    bool result;

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", fileName, extension]]]) {
        result = TRUE;
    } else {
        result = FALSE;
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Set**

```
UIButton * button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
UIImage * backgroundImage = [self loadImage:@"YourImageName" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]];

[button setImage:backgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

---

### **-Edited-**

I believe your problem is that you are returning 0 in your `loadImages` method. Instead of returning the image itself.

This is how I accomplished it:

**Load**

```
-(UIImage *) loadImage:(NSString *)fileName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {

    UIImage * result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@", directoryPath, fileName, extension]];

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"i224_mag2.png"]; // it is only for bundle. You should use 

[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]
```

or

```
 [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Update:

I use category for UIButton class.

```
- (void)loadImage:(NSString *)URL withActivityIndicator:(BOOL)hasActivity refreshObject:(UIView *)refresh{

   // load image from cache cutted   
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
//this will start the image loading in bg
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{  

    NSData *image = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];

    //this will set the image when loading is finished
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIImage *loadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:image];

 // add image to cache cutted

        [self setImage:loadedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    });
});
```

}

Comment: how can I add file name? should I use this : `path = [path stringByAppendingString:@"/yourLocalImage.png"];`

Answer (score 0):

You are making NSData using `dataWithContentsOfFile:` API. you should use `dataWithContentsOfURL` instead.

```
    NSString *urlMag1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myweb.com/i224_mag1.png"];
    NSString *urlMag2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myweb.com/i224_mag2.png"];


    NSData *image1 = [NSdata contentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlMag1]];

    NSData *image2 = [NSdata contentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlMag2]];


    [mag2 setBackgroundImage:imgMag1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Usually `[NSdata contentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlMag1]];` will freeze UI until image downloading complete.